# Generate function between 0 and 1 on both axis

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am trying to create different function between 0 and 1 on both axis which can take the following shape. (more like logit curve)

I want to experiment the shape as well a little more.

I was referring to this [thread here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2052182/is-there-a-probability-distribution-with-a-cdf-shaped-like-the-sinh-or-logit-fun), however the limits are between -1 to 1.

any idea how can I achieve it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your shape looks a bit like
$$f(x)=x+b\sin(2\pi x)$$
for some constant $b$.  If you want more wiggles you can try
$$f(x)=x+b_1\sin(\pi x)+b_2\sin(2\pi x)+\cdots+b_n\sin(n\pi x)$$
and play around with the constants.